# VBA script should return name of worksheet if a non zero value exists in a certain range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a report that will churn out a single workbook with multiple worksheets. However, I'm only interested in finding out if there is a **non zero** value in a range; i.e `Range("B33:J33")`. Assuming out of the 10 worksheets, 3 of them have non zero values in the suggested range.

Would I be able to prompt a message box that tells me which 3 worksheets have the non zero values?

```
Dim rngToCheck As Range
Set rngToCheck = Range("B33:J33")
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Integer
Dim active As Integer, count As Integer

Worksheets(1).Select
count = Worksheets.count
active = ActiveSheet.Index + 1
counter = 0

Do Until active > count

    rngToCheck.Select

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        counter = counter + 1
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next

Loop

msgbox counter
```

Comment: It's quite easy to achieve what you want and I can give you a code for this right away. However, in the spirit of a [**good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is what we expect from you it'd be great if you tell/show us what you have already tried to solve your problem. Have you got **any** code that you wrote that possibly needs improvement?

Comment: See above edit, I've tried the following, however, an error occured. Any advice for which part I've got it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First define at your sub:

```
Dim rngToCheck as Range
Set rngToCheck = Range("B33:J33") 
Dim cell as Range
Dim counter as Integer

counter =0
```

Run a `FOR EACH` loop for every sheet and sheet, and inside it run another `FOR EACH` loop that says:

```
rngToCheck.Select

FOR EACH cell in Selection
    IF cell.Value <>"0" then
        counter = counter+1
    end if
next
```

and then, just a simple if condition for the counter value, if it will be zero, no cell found, else did found...

Comment: See above edit, I've tried the following, however, an error occured. Any advice for which part I've got it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Dim wr, r As Integer, nr As Integer
nr = Sheets.Count
For r = 1 To nr
 With Sheets(r)
  If Application.CountIf(.Range("B33:J33"), "<>0") - Application.CountBlank(.Range("B33:J33")) > 0 Then
   MsgBox .name
  End If
 End With
Next
```

I assume you don't want, as well, empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sheetNames(1 to 100) As String
Dim snIndex As Integer

snIndex = 1
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
    For Each cll in rngToCheck
        If cll.Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(cll.Value) Then
                If cll.Value > 0 Then
                    sheetNames(snIndex) = sheet.Name
                    snIndex = snIndex + 1
                    Break For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cll
Next sht

Dim message As String
message = ""
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 to snIndex - 1
    message = message & "; " & sheetNames(i)
Next i

msgbox message
```